# Files not sent (msdos/ftp)

Tags: ftp, ms-dos

I have a problem. I tried to upload a video to my company platform by ftp using msdos comands. The conection does ok and it returns the message "ftp: 687036 bytes sent in 1.75s  393.49kbytes/s.
ftp>"

I really need to send this archives. Someone could help me?

Comment: Does your video file size correspond with the roughly 680kB ftp claimed to have transferred? And if so, i suppose sending it by email is not an option? Have you tried other ftp clients?

Comment: You probably mean command line. MS DOS was an OS and I think you're using Windows, not DOS.